# Handling "404 image error" error with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, error-handling, youtube, http-status-code-404, image

When loading a thumbnail of a video hosted by Youtube, a 404 error is an actual image. eg:
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/eMFYg2oZ4qE/default.jpg
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/0/default.jpg

Since the error presents itself as a authentic image,

```
<img onerror="alert('error!')" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/0/default.jpg">
```

does not work in catching the 404 error... How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what `onerror` is supposed to do as its not valid html, but this question about image error handling with php might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025065/why-wont-this-code-work

Comment: `onerror` is valid. http://theglenbot.com/html-image-tag-onerror-attribute/

Comment: onerror is good, but like in my comment below, it's not technically a 404, it's just a default response from the YouTube Server.

Comment: I'm wondering this myself actually...

Answer (score 3):

I believe those are handled server-side on YouTube, but since you tagged this as jQuery, using a small group of images, you could check their existence with a simple AJAX request, then on failure, change the "src" attribute to your default image path.

```
$.ajax("/path/to/image.img", failure: function() {
  $('#this-image').attr('src', 'default.jpg');
})
```

Dummy selectors in that, you'd need to make it fit the logic of your application

Comment: Although you did say dummy selectors that would change all images to default.jpg.

Comment: I had the understanding that cross domain ajax is not possible without heavy weight code(through some kind of proxy eg. php). I'd like to keep it light weight as possible.

Comment: Ok, I think I better understand your problem now. Unfortunately, this is all handled server-side, and unless you start using the API (which I suggest either way) there's no "easy, lightweight" way of doing this

Comment: For your reference: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api

Comment: @KyleMacey There IS indeed a lightweight version of it; updating the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Consciousness ...to distinguish between two images of the same filename? You'd have to elaborate...

Comment: @Consciousness OP is not actually receiving a 404, YouTube just defaults to a specific image if no thumbnail is found, without changing the name of the file or response. It's all server side

Comment: Actually, I am receiving a 404. Check the headers.

Comment: Well look at that... This is still something best handled with the API. There's much more you can do dynamically if you want to stay unobtrusive

Comment: I have a large database of videos that cannot be updated regularly. The API is for the backend. This is for the front end just in case a user of my database stumbles across a video which has been removed. I was hoping that I can somehow take advantage of the 404 header and be efficient but I guess there isn't a simple and ideal solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Set default image to some local image. and if ajax request is passed, then use server image.

```
        var defaultImage = "/images/default_user.jpg";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/image.img',
            failure: function () {  
                 alert('Image not found in server');            
            },
            success: function () {
                defaultImage = "/path/to/image.img";
            }
        });
```