# Set the value "img broken" in a GTM dataLayer on 404 image

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404, google-tag-manager, broken-image

I need to set a dataLayer event when a user view a broken image in the front end. I have a lot of errors in the console but I'm not able to pass this info into a dataLayer like:

```js
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'broken_img',
    'eventCategory': '404',
    'eventAction': 'Broken Img',
    'eventLabel': document.location.pathname
});
```

When the page is loaded. Any suggests for a generic JS or jQuery Code?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821155/handling-404-image-error-error-with-jquery-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611761/set-the-value-img-broken-in-a-gtm-datalayer-on-404-image

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with `onerror`:

```
<img onerror="pushError(this.src)" src="https://mydomain/myimg.jpg">

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function pushError(src) {
  dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'broken_img',
      'eventCategory': '404',
      'eventAction': 'Broken Img',
      'eventLabel': src
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Michele, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I need a custom HTML because I cannot set anything inside the source code. Any ideas?